# Boot Loop - Trying to make a Yosemite KVM VM w/Chameleon Bootloader

Tags: macos, startup, virtualization, kvm

I am trying to boot a Yosemite VM (10.10.5) following these instructions [here](http://www.contrib.andrew.cmu.edu/~somlo/OSXKVM/).

But it gets stuck in a loop at the BIOS boot screen (the OS has not yet been installed)

My hardware is a Mac mini with Ubuntu 14.04 installed (I specifically need to use KVM to boot OS X VMs for my use case), hardware is:
CPU: GenuineIntel, Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4578U CPU@3.00GHz
Graphics card: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT integrated graphics controller (rev 09)
Motherboard: Apple Mac-35C5E0812OC7EEAF
I have QEMU 2.6.0, and Chameleon Enoch r2839 (I've also tried Chameleon 2.3 r2838 with the same results)

The command I use to boot is:

```
bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm -m 2048 \
      -cpu core2duo,vendor=GenuineIntel \
  -machine q35 \
  -usb -device usb-kbd -device usb-mouse \
  -device isa-applesmc,osk="insert-real-64-char-OSK-string-here" \
  -kernel ./chameleon_enoch\
  -smbios type=2 \
  -device ide-drive,bus=ide.2,drive=MacHDD \
  -drive id=MacHDD,if=none,file=./mac_hdd.img \
  -netdev user,id=hub0port0 \
  -device e1000-82545em,netdev=hub0port0,id=mac_vnet0 \
  -monitor stdio \
  -device ide-drive,bus=ide.0,drive=MacDVD \
  -drive id=MacDVD,if=none,snapshot=on,file=./Yosemite.10.10.2.iso
      -vnc 127.0.0.1:2
```

(real string osk string is inserted here, I just didn't add it for public posting)

When I boot, I get to this screen just fine:
[image: original boot screen]

When I boot with -v option, it gets to these screens, goes black, and then returns to the original boot screen shown previously: 
[image: attempt1screen1]

[image: attempt1screen2]
There does not appear to be any obvious errors or kernel panics. I googled the DSDT and SMBios messages and they don't appear to be anything that would cause issues in this case.

If I try booting it in safe mode (-v -x), I get these screens before it once again returns to the original boot screen:
[image: attempt2screen1]
[image: attempt2screen2]
Again, no obvious crashes or panics.

I've tried various combinations of -v, -f, -x, GraphicsEnabler=Yes/No, the behavior is basically always the same. Keep in mind, I am trying to boot and install OS X in a virtual machine, not on the computer itself.

Can anyone see any problems or suggest other troubleshooting I could do?

Comment: The SLA for OS X Yosemite does allow for its virtualization only on Apple-branded hardware however another requirement is it also has to be virtualized under a running occurrence of OS X not another OS on Apple-branded hardware.

Comment: Hmm, ok, I didn't realize it had to be also be running the software. That said, it's possible my company has a different SLA as this is for commercial use. I will have to ask further about my personal situation, but my question still stands.

Comment: @user3439894 I can't find the obligation to **not** run a virtualized OS X under a non-OS X operating system in the EULA. Where did you find it?

Comment: @klanomath, In the SLA [OSX1011.pdf](http://images.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1011.pdf) Section 2, B, i & iii are the key parts.

Comment: @user3439894 2,B,i (only Apple hardware) is obvious, but in my opinion 2,B,iii allows to run e.g a virtualized OS X under Windows & VMware in a Boot Camp partition on Apple hardware. The german part (2,B,iii page 25 of 397) of the SLA doesn't even mention that OS X has to be installed on the Apple hardware and would allow KVM & a virtualized OS X.

Comment: @klanomath, I'm not going to get into a legal discussion here, that's what lawyers are for. Anyway, the issue got resolved. That said, OS X runs like crap under virtualization compared to running natively on Apple-branded hardware and not all features are available under virtualization as well. So to me it seems absurd to install Linux on Apple-branded hardware to then install OS X in a VM under Linux. But to each their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually solved this: I had to upgrade from Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 and use just the `GraphicsEnabler=No` flag as a boot option. You enter it in the same place after `boot:` that the `-v` flag in the first screenshot.

Disclaimer:
As far as the legal issues brought up in the comments, most people I talked to did not think you had to actively be running OS X on the machine, as you are allowed do things like run a different version of OS X in a VM, or use VMWare ESXi. I am not a lawyer and did not talk to one, so any individual concerned would have to consult their own legal team.